# gradle kotlin dsl: copy project dependencies

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I can copy all dependencies of a module in a multimodule gradle project with a task like

```
tasks.register<Sync>("copyResources") {
    from(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
    into(layout.buildDirectory.dir("extraResources"))
}
```

But actually, I only need to copy the [project dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sub:project_dependencies) by applying a filter with project group id.
*Something like*

```
tasks.register<Sync>("copyResources") {
    from(configurations.runtimeClasspath) {
        include {
            group "this.project.group"   // NOT WORKING.
        }
    }
    into(layout.buildDirectory.dir("extraResources"))
}
```

What is the right way to do this in Gradle with Kotlin DSL?

Comment: Where is that group function supposed to come from, I don't think that's even valid in groovy dsl? I've never used the Sync task, but all the examples on the docs use file path's in the include, you could probably look for the paths of the files you want, add a filter a la 'this/project/group/*' and be done with it. Also`include` takes a parameter, not a lambda, so don't use curly braces.

Comment: @somethingsomething My requirement is to copy "project dependencies" excluding the third party dependencies. The second code snippet in the question is there to only hint what I want to achieve and it not working code as already documented there.

Answer (score 0):

The following works.
But I feel there must be a simpler solution.

This solution uses regular expressions to filter out dependencies. The regex match is true if the absolute path of the dependency file contains the multimodule project root in it.

```kotlin
val copyImplemtations by configurations.creating {
    extendsFrom(configurations.implementation.get())
}

tasks.register<Sync>("copyResources") {
    val regex = Regex(".*[\\\\/]kotlin-spring-demo[\\\\/].*")
    from(copyImplemtations.filter { regex.matches(it.absolutePath) })
    into(layout.buildDirectory.dir("extraResources"))
}
```